# How to disable mouse scroll wheel button permanently

Tags: winapi, win32gui

I have a question that's bothering me. So I have a friend whose mouse scroll wheel just broke, but not mechanically, it's just went crazy - scrolling by itself without any input. I wrote a simple c++/batch program, which asks you if you wanna disable scroll button by modifying values in registry:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v "WheelScrollChars" /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v "WheelScrollLines" /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f
```

Unfortunately, it works only in some applications e.g. chrome. Like when he opens Adobe Premiere or any additional software, the scroll actually is not disabled - it keeps scrolling by itself randomly up and down. Yeah, I know that's not a problem to buy a new mouse, but I'm just curious if there's any other way around it. And I found a piece of software called X-Mouse Button Control (written in C/C++ I guess), which actually have an option to disable scrolling permanently but it only works while program is running. I tried to reverse its binary in IDA although couldn't find actual function used to disable scrolling in whole system, not just couple of Windows apps.

So I thought I'd ask, maybe you have some ideas if there are possibilities in C++ to make it disabled in whole Windows (within any application running)? I guess if someone did it via this software, X-Mouse Button Control, it's probably possible but I haven't found anything yet. Anyway, any help is much appreciated and I'm looking forward to your replies, thanks!

Comment: Or you could spend $10 on a new mouse...

Comment: Most probably the program you mentioned works by inserting its [mouse hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644986(v=VS.85).aspx) into the system input queue.

Comment: You can disable Mouse Wheel with a **WH_MOUSE_LL** Hook (just by returning 1 when _wParam == WM_MOUSEWHEEL_)... but of course the program must be running.

Comment: Registry values only control the preferred scroll distance, apps can do custom handling if they want. Low level hook is the only software option AFAIK.

Comment: Yep, as I said it's not about spending $10 on a new mouse, I'm just trying to learn new things as I'm quite a beginner in C++ so I thought it might be a good lesson. Thanks for the hooks idea, I've already been reading about them as it's a new thing for me right now. Could anyone, please, give me some examples how does it work? Do I make a dll or is it just simple couple lines of code? I've been checking microsoft docs on SetWindowsHookEx function but honestly I don't really get it, and there are not many tutorials on that subject. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need any DLL for Low Level hooks. It is just a few lines of code (in _LowLevelMouseProc_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The method has been given in the comments. All I have done is to
>   familiarize you with the use of hook.

**The following is the most concise implementation code for your reference:**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

HHOOK mouseHook;

LRESULT __stdcall MouseHookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {       
        case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(mouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook()
{
    if (!(mouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookCallback, NULL, 0)))
    {
        cout << "Failed to install mouse hook!" << endl;
    }
}

void ReleaseHook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(mouseHook);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    SetHook();
    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

The mouse wheel is intercepted by the mouse hook, so that the mouse wheel is disabled.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted to achieve, it works perfectly!